# Regex to convert quotes

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, regex-group

Given this pattern:

```
    abc/09dce097-34e1-4af3-ab97-9eccd1163615.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/29ef1c15-f2b3-4b4c-9a34-7de982abfb22.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/50dff7db-1bd6-48fa-b608-9e1b70a92bea.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/6092d7ee-0349-40b0-8342-4ccfe63d0297.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/64701479-62c2-4930-b85d-70c610790cc1.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/6d165c85-1499-4d36-bb4f-63d67a9503b6.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/7ab224e7-3be3-4394-8e51-7b9eb85617b8.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/8335bd20-bf16-44d0-b1f7-c898ea81749a.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/df125f62-6183-4117-a6f6-0119d2777a59.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/e91aa1b1-0bd6-4316-b03a-dd4326a82149.json
    "1010101010"
    abc/ff33010e-d20f-4c44-b560-6e5e40fbb3ad.json
    "1010101010"
```

I want to generate this using regex:

```
    '1010101010','1010101010','1010101010','1010101010','1010101010','1010101010','1010101010','1010101010','1010101010','1010101010','1010101010'
```

My current regex matcher is:

```
    \n?.*.json\n
```

Replacing all in my text editor with a comma:

```
    ,
```

But it only carries me as far as:

```
    ,"1010101010","1010101010","1010101010","1010101010","1010101010","1010101010","1010101010","1010101010","1010101010","1010101010","1010101010"
```

From where I manually fix the rest.

Is there a regex one-liner that I can use?

Comment: Something like this, and then remove the last comma `.*\.json\n[^\S\n]*"([01]+)"` https://regex101.com/r/iqLxkT/1 or https://regex101.com/r/NTNwbp/1

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Comment: That's lovely!  Thank you!  Really need to get rid of the last comma without any further action though.

I've edited it to - \n?.*\.json\n[^\S\n]*"(.+)"

Comment: In Notepad++ you could do a conditional replacement I think, but which editor are you using? If you just use a comma in the replacement it will be there for every replacement.

Comment: Is conversion from `"` to `'` more important for you or getting commas in right place?

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Conversion from " to '  is important due to its time saving nature.  The number of items could grow to as great as 50+.

Comment: @ anubhava - still have the last comma.

Comment: Sorry I meant this one: https://regex101.com/r/ekdf0P/1

Comment: That's giving me double quotes around the first item.  But you've definitely given me a good starting point :-)

Comment: Or do 2 replacements. First `.*\.json\R\h*"(\d+)"\R?` and replace with `'$1',` like https://regex101.com/r/SHvSNX/1  and then `((?:'\d+'(?:,'\d+')+)+),` and replace with `$1` like https://regex101.com/r/9EkkpE/1

Comment: Interesting.  Needs to be a single op though.

Comment: From what Im reading, negative lookahead looks promising.

Comment: This can never be done in one operation, as the replacement part needs to decide whether to only replace a double quote, or also to insert a comma. This cannot be done with the capabilities available in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: yeah definitely not possible to achieve everything in a single search/replace in IntelliJ

Comment: I think the closest you can get with *one* regex replacement is `.*\.json\n\s*"(.*)"\n` and replace with `,'$1'`. Then you have one comma to remove at the very start of the generated output.